# navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition always get a error code 3: timeout expired

Tags: android, geolocation

I am using cordova-2.0.0 and android emulator google api level16.

Whenever I run `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` I always get `error3`.
my code brief is as:

```
     // Wait for Cordova to load
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

            // Cordova is ready
            function onDeviceReady() {
                console.log("Entering index.html.onDeviceReady");
                var networkState = navigator.network.connection.type;
                getPosition(networkState);
}

function getPosition(networkState) {
    console.log("Entering getPosition function");
    console.log("networkState is: " + networkState);
    if (networkState !== null) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, {
            maximumAge : Infinity,
            timeout : 5000,
            enableHighAccuracy : true
        });
    } else {
        alert('Please check your network connection and try again.');
    }
    console.log("Leaving getPosition function");
}

// function for lat & lng
function onSuccess(position) {
    console.log("Entering onSuccess(position) function");
    console.log("Latitude is: " + position.coords.latitude);
    console.log("longitude is: " + position.coords.longitude);
    lat = position.coords.latitude;
    lng = position.coords.longitude;
    console.log("Leaving onSuccess(position) function");
}

// function for lat & lng
function onError(error) {
    console.log("Entering onError(error) function");
    alert('code: ' + error.code + '\n' + 'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    console.log("Leaving onError(error) function");
}
```

**If anyone have idea why `error3` is raised, please give suggestions. Thanks a lot**

Comment: You have a lot of debug output... what is on your console when error is raised ?

Comment: as i can see, it goes directly into the function onError();

Answer (score 5):

I did set

```
enableHighAccuracy: false
```

too, but dreading "error code 3" kept popping out...
Neither

```
browser / settings / privacy and security / position / delete position access data
```

did help...
Only power cycling (but I suppose a browser kill would do the same) Android (4.1.2) did force the browser to repeat the question "Share position?" to the user, throw error code 3 out of the door...

I suppose in some situation (that I can't repeat, sorry) the browser stores an invalid position for that site - or - remembers a sharing denial for that site...

Sorry for late answering (and perhaps in an incomplete way)... If somebody has better evidence please share it... :-)

Answer (score 2):

This stumped me for quite a while.
Basically the only way I can get it to return data is by *specifically* passing

```
enableHighAccuracy: false
```

It always times out if I enable it.